# Access constants from nested C# class in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

Let's say I have a class defined something like the below:

```
namespace MyProject.MyConstants
{
    public class Constants
    {
        public class Group1Constants
        {
            public const string DoIt= "DoIt";
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use this const, from a separate project, in my xaml.  I included the namespace:

```
xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:MyProject.MyConstants;assembly=MyProject.MyConstants"
```

and am trying to use the constant as follows:

```
<MenuItem Header="{x:Static controls:Constants.Group1Constants.DoIt}">
```

The above wont compile though, saying that

```
Cannot find the type 'Constants.Group1Constants'. Note that type names are case sensitive.
```

I must be missing something simple.  All I want to do is use some constants from a class in  different project in my xaml.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<MenuItem Header="{x:Static constants:Constants+Group1Constants.DoIt}">
```

I used "+" instead of "." to reference the nested class.  Not sure if you'll run into problems doing this though.

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it!  I have never seen the "+" syntax before.

Comment: wtf is the "+" syntax?

Comment: Thank You, WPF amazes me with its Syntaxes

Comment: Unless it is a static class or an object, we cannot access a property but how can we able to access it XAML ?

Answer (score 1):

For textbox label text field constants in XAML I use:

```
Text="{x:Static local:[myConstantNamesClass].[name of constant string in your constant class]}"
```

and then need to build the solution to make it accessible.

(Note that the local: XAML namespace would be set to reference the CLR namespace of the Constants class at the very top of the XAML file.)